# Firefox extension: gBrowser is not defined

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

This is a Firefox extension and everything is working pretty good.

BUT...
I keep getting the irritating "gBrowser is not defined" error in the console because of this line:

```
gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab("chrome://ire_TPB/content/options.html");
```

What I am trying to do of course is open a new tab and load that local html page.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Win 7 ult
FF 7.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Getting_access_to_the_browser): "If gBrowser isn't defined your code is either not running in the scope of the browser window or running too early. You can access gBrowser only after the browser window is fully loaded."

Comment: I see! Thanks for that! How do you suggest I get past that? What tricks do you use?

Comment: Because even in the onload i have this: 
`this.onLoad = function ()   {gBrowser.addProgressListener(self.ire_TPB_urlBarListener);}` which throws that same damn error

Comment: Is it running in a sidebar or in the main browser window?

Comment: @Ryan: are you sure? And is onLoad actually called after on the load event? The problem (if you haven't solved it yet) is not in the snippets you posted...

Comment: Code seems to be working none the less, only on first install it is throwing that error. Will post back if it becomes a major problem. Thanks for replying guys!

Comment: And what does `this` refer to in your `this.onLoad` above? Are you sure?